# Converting varchar mm/dd/yy to date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to migrate data from one table to other. The issue is my target table has type date yyyy-mm-dd where as the source table has type varchar mm/dd/yy
I tried a few thing but seems none worked.

I am trying this but seems to give null

```
select year((datecreated)) * 10000 + month((datecreated)) * 100 + day((datecreated)) from employee
```

Here employee is my table and datecreated is my column.

If someone has come across this please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Data in tables is typed, not formatted... unless you mean you've got dates represented as, e.g., VARCHAR in your table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert a string to a date:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datecreated,'%m/%d/%Y') as date
FROM employee
```

Date format specifications (%m, etc) can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).