# How to convert date from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd in MySQL? Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a large dataset with employees' time entries. The current date format is **MM/dd/yyyy**. However, I need to convert all the dates into **yyyy-MM-dd format**.

I have tried the following:

Update human_resources.timekeeping
Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%d-%m-%Y');

Got the errror messsage **Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date.**

My SQL version is **5.7.18-log.**

I tried to view SQL mode using **SELECT @@sql_mode;** and I got **NO ENGINE SUBSTITUTION.**

I have tried to retrieve the value like shown below and it was working fine.
[Converting varchar mm/dd/yy to date format yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560235/converting-varchar-mm-dd-yy-to-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd+)

However, updating the data would not work. I need to update the actual records, not insert new records.

Hope someone can help me regarding this. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: The data type for Actual_Date is VARCHAR.**

Apologies if my explanation may be a bit confusing. But I am using this data set to display and filter time entries in a gridview. When I am filtering dates, say for example (01/15/2022-01/25/2022), data from 2021 is also being displayed. When I tried to manually change the format of some of my data in sql to yyyy-MM-dd, my code seemed to be working fine. The problem is there are a lot of data in this table, which is why manually updating the format is impossible. What is the first thing that I need to do? I'm sorry this is all still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Why is MM capitalised in MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share more details here. What's the data type of your column `Actual_Date`? You could also share some demo rows from the table.

Comment: Better even: don't store dates or timestamps as strings but as a date/time column type and only convert to the desired string format when displaying the values to the user. This way, you won't have to worry about any format internally and everyone can display a date value in his desired format ...

Comment: @P.Salmon "mm" would be for minutes in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies if you have already taken the following things into consideration but I thought them worth mentioning.

Given that you say this is a "large dataset" I assume this is a table that is currently in use. Does the existing application rely on the `Actual_Date` being in that string format? Does it rely on a fixed number of columns in the table? Some poorly written applications can be very brittle when it comes to changing underlying data structure.

You may want to consider creating a copy of the current table, modifying the structure of the copy, and replacing the original with a view with the same columns and formats as the original. This way you get improved data but reduce risk to existing application.

In the title and first line of your question you state that the current format is `MM/dd/yyyy`

```
Update human_resources.timekeeping Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: Yes, this table is currently in use. Apologies if my explanation may be a bit confusing. But I am using this data set to display and filter time entries in a gridview. When I am filtering dates, say for example (01/15/2022-01/25/2022), data from 2021 is also being displayed. When I tried to manually change the format of some of my data in sql to yyyy-MM-dd, my code seemed to be working fine. The problem is there are a lot of data in this table, which is why manually updating the format is impossible. What is the first thing that I need to do? I'm sorry this is all still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Upvote for this one. I tried it and I don't know why but it worked. @george you must just try changing your current separator from `-` to `/`. Try this sample select and this will show you the magic `SELECT '11/02/2021' AS 'Old Date', STR_TO_DATE('11/02/2021', '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'New Date';`

This will convert `11/02/2021` to  `2021-11-02`.

Comment: By changing the format of the date in Actual_Date are you going to break some other application? If you bulk update the value in Actual_Date and get it wrong, it may not be recoverable. Does this matter? If nothing else depends on this data, then crack on and update it using the query I provided. Try with a where clause (WHERE id = 1) added first to make sure it functions as intended. If there are dependencies which mean you should not update the data in place, explain them in your question.

Comment: @TheCoolCat Hi! Thank you for your comment. I tried the query above as well and it did show me the magic! hahaha. That simple separator made it all happen!

Comment: @nnichols Thank you so much for your helpful answer! I don't think I have enough reputation to upvote your answer but THANK YOU SO MUCH! I tried it and it worked! You don't know how thankful I am.

I tried your query and the dates did change. However, I am getting this warning message.

104879 row(s) affected, 13 warning(s):
1411 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-01-11' for function str_to_date

Last time I tried changing the data type from VARCHAR to DATE, it gave me error messages. But after running your query, I tried to change the datatype to DATE again. Somehow, it was nowsuccessful?

Comment: @nnichols Okay, uhm. I am a bit confused right now. After my previous comment of changing the data type to DATE. The Actual_Date column is displaying 2021-11-02 in SQL. However, I noticed that the display in my gridview is showing 1/12/2022 12:00:00 AM. Should I revert it to VARCHAR again?

Comment: The warnings should have been the few values that were already in the correct format. At least your dates are being stored as dates now. A step in the right direction. You will probably need to ask another question asking for help with your gridview. Do not re-break your date data to get your grid view to work! You need to figure out how to make it work for your environment.

Comment: Hi! I'm back and I need your help again. For this new problem I have a mix of data format in one table. Some time entries are in the format of MM/dd/yyyy while some are in the format yyyy-MM-dd.

I need to change my old format MM/dd/yyyy to my new format yyyy-MM-dd.

I'm trying to use the same query 

Update human_resources.time_entry_request Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y'); 

but I'm encountering the following error:

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2021-05-08' for function str_to_date

Comment: Hi! Need help with the same scenario, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845258/how-to-convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-mysql-error-code-1411-in Posted it here so I can explain it better. Would appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 0):

Your separator is / not -

%d-%m-%Y >> %d/%m/%Y

Comment: Hi ! May I ask if this would work even if the format needed is yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: This will give a wrong date format and may throw an Error. The Month will be considered as Day and Day will be Month. `11/02/2021` will become `2021-02-11` which is incorrect.