# How to convert date from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd in MySQL? Error: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date

I just need help on how to convert date from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd in MySQL?

I already asked this question a few months ago, and I was able to successfully convert it. Please see thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845258/how-to-convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-mysql-error-code-1411-in/70845662?noredirect=1#comment125264745_70845662).

However, I'm having difficulty with this new dataset. Previously, when I created thie previous post, **ALL** of my dataset were in the format MM/dd/yyyy, to which I successfully converted to yyyy-MM-dd using the following query:

```
Update human_resources.timekeeping Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

However, for this new problem that I am encountering, I have a **mix** of data format in one table. Some time entries are in the format of MM/dd/yyyy while some are in the format yyyy-MM-dd. (Datatype is **VARCHAR**)

I need to change my **old** format **MM/dd/yyyy** to my **new** format **yyyy-MM-dd.**

I'm trying to use the same query:

```
Update human_resources.time_entry_request Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

but I'm encountering the following error:

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2021-05-08' for function
> str_to_date

On the other hand, I tried to use this query: (Specified the actual date in the where clause)

```
Update human_resources.time_entry_request Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') where Actual_Date = "05/31/2021";
```

and it was **successful**. (Changing specific MM/dd/yyyy time entry to format yyyy-MM-dd).

I believe the error that is causing this problem is that the dataset already contains the new and accurate format which is the yyyy-MM-dd.

It also happens vice versa, tried to change the new format into the old one so I can change them to the new one altogether.

PS. The data type for Actual_Date is `VARCHAR`. I tried changing it to `DATE()` but am receiving this error:

Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `human_resources`.`time_entry_request` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Actual_Date` `Actual_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
> the database.

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect date value: '06/04/2021' for
> column 'Actual_Date' at row 17

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `human_resources`.`time_entry_request` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Actual_Date` `Actual_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Is there a way I can change the old format to the new one, please? Would really appreciate your help! The dataset contains a mix of MM/dd/yyyy while some are in the format yyyy-MM-dd

My previous post contains ALL MM/dd/yyyy so I was able to convert it successfully.

Comment: I suggest trying [regexp_like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like), i.e. `Update human_resources.time_entry_request Set Actual_Date = str_to_date(Actual_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') where regexp_like(Actual_Date, '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9]{4}')`

Comment: Hi @Abra, thank you for your suggestion. I tried to run the query, however I am getting the following error: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION human_resources.regexp_like does not exist 0.000 sec.